# Long 53+ second startup on a decent laptop. What to do?

Tags: boot, dual-boot

My laptop has a decent i5 processor, 8 gigs of ram. I have dual booted it with Ubuntu 16.04 but it takes too long to boot.

Some information:

```
systemd-analyze
```

returns,

```
Startup finished in 2.630s (firmware) + 2.417s (loader) + 4.067s (kernel) + 44.125s (userspace) = 53.240s
```

and

```
systemd-analyze critical-chain
```

returns,

```
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @44.100s
└─multi-user.target @44.100s
  └─mysql.service @37.972s +6.127s
    └─network.target @37.951s
      └─wpa_supplicant.service @40.980s +419ms
        └─basic.target @33.530s
          └─sockets.target @33.529s
            └─snapd.socket @33.504s +17ms
              └─sysinit.target @33.495s
                └─apparmor.service @22.549s +10.945s
                  └─local-fs.target @22.437s
                    └─boot-efi.mount @22.080s +356ms
                      └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4C19\x2dC7DF.service @11.596s +10.419
                        └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4C19\x2dC7DF.device @11.575s
lines 1-17/17 (END)
```

First, is this performance normal? How might I make improvements?
Thanks.

Comment: I find `systemd-analyze blame` helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Googled it. here are some things to try

1. http://www.howtogeek.com/69753/how-to-cut-your-linux-pcs-boot-time-in-half-with-e4rat/
2. http://www.howtogeek.com/115797/6-ways-to-speed-up-ubuntu/
3. PS moderator i know this IS just some links but im just trying to help some people !

   4. PPS my 2011 mainstream PC gos to GRUB in 25 secs & linux mint with SDD boots in 26 sec